# Is it possible to add Search in User Profile answers & questions

Tags: feature-request, search, profile-page

My question is ***Is it possible to add Search in User Profile answers & questions***.

I will explain with scenario.

Let's say I want to post some answer and I have already answered that question.

Now for searching my answer what I do is go to profile and click answer.

Now search for that keyword (luckily I remember some words of that question(

If not found, click index (for next answers) & repeat till you found.

***I have to keep on clicking table index options to find that answer.***

If I would have `Search` option, it could have filtered all questions that I answered finding keyword.

Comment: Have you tried searching for: "user:1066828 keyword"

Comment: @Mysticial : nope, let me search right away...

Comment: @Mysticial : its not showing because its searching for `view` as word and not sub-substring of word. I searched with `user:1066828 view` & I didn't found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22524846/created-table-cell-with-uiview-as-subview-not-displaying-in-ios7/22524896) question in it. This question is present in [my answered list](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1066828/fahim-parkar?tab=answers&sort=newest&page=2)

Comment: @Mysticial : and if this is feature, I would say it's not user friendly... As I see you have [high rep](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/922184/mysticial), you know, but think from the user who is new to this website or don't use this website on daily basis...

Comment: It's not *that* user-unfriendly. If you go to your profile, the search bar already has "user:1066828" in it. So you can just append your keyword. And no, rep has nothing do with this.

Comment: If you've already answered the question, make sure you are marking it as a duplicate if it is indeed the same question, not copying your old answer into the new question as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Mysticial indicated, the feature already exists.

All you need to include is `user:xxxxxx` where xxxxxx is the user id of the user you want to search.  Note, I said user id and not display name.  The user id can be found in the URL of the profile:

> [image]

but if you want to search your own posts, you can just put `me` instead of the user id and it will automatically substitute your own user id, presuming you are logged in at the time.

The syntax is easily available in the advanced search tips.  You can find the syntax on the advanced search help tips found in the side bar of every search:

> [image]

To make this even simpler, the `user:xxxxxxx` is prepopulated when you visit any user's profile.

I'll admit that it is not very intuitive, but there's not much more SE can do to highlight this different that isn't done already.